When transfering a RAID array to new computer, do the RAID adapter drivers need to be the same?
I have a Plex server running on Fedora 36 Server, with an ARECA 1883 controller running two RAID enclosures (approx. 500TB). I am currently building a new server, again on Fedora, with the goal of transferring the two arrays. I understand that as long as I relocate the ARECA controller along with arrays, and as long as the drives remain in the same position, I shouldn't lose any data. Still, I thought of a potential glitch: do I need to keep the same ARECA driver release currently installed on the old server (I have not updated the drivers in years, as the system has been running just fine) or can I install a later, more current version and still expect the data to remain unaffected? Similarly, does the Fedora Server release need to remain the same (36) or can I install release 40 and still transfer the array without problems? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

There is a lot of "should" in this answer, but given what you've told us, pretty much any answer is going to have that.
Generally speaking, the geometry of the data in the arrays of a hardware RAID system will be dependent on the firmware in the controller. So long as there is no major update to the RAID controller firmware, the data should remain safe.
The driver is an interface layer between the firmware and the OS. While it may have hooks that would control the way the firmware sees the disks, in normal operation it should have no effect on the geometry and so it shouldn't affect data security to update the driver to the latest.
Because the driver and the firmware have been given the responsibility for handling the geometry, the OS should be seeing the disk as nothing but a large block device. It will have no input or expectations about geometry and so should be able to just use the arrays as is.
If you have to change controller, of course, all bets are off.
If you are at all unsure of yourself: three words: back it up.

A regular backup is mandatory during normal operation and especially before moving any data.

Yes. One issue is that OP did mention he's talking about a 500TB array here, which might be difficult to back up. Me, I'd spring for 20 or so 20+TB drives and RAID them at least temporarily as backup; definitely cheaper than rebuilding all that data, I'd guess.

thank you for your help - I do have a backup routine (1/year full 500TB backup, then incrementals every 2/3 months as other videos are added) so my full library is backed up as of now - just hoping that a smooth transfer will keep me from having to restore 500TB of video files
